# What is the process for transferring data from an old Artifactory version to the most recent version?

Tags: artifactory

We have an old Artifactory repository running Pro v5.x (License Expired).

We are planning to use Artifactory again in our pipeline by purchasing a license for the latest Artifactory version. The old instance contains critical artifacts that are important to the organization.

Is there a method for transferring old artifacts and docker images from an old JFrog Artifactory instance to a newer version after purchasing a new license, without losing any data?

Comment: If the old instance contains critical artifacts then it isn't really unused, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things can be done here

1. Install the new license to existing server and upgrade it to latest version (7.x)

- Follow this [document](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/upgrading-from-artifactory-version-below-6.10) to upgrade to version 6.10 first
- Follow this [document](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/upgrading-from-artifactory-version-6.10.x-onwards-to-7.x) to upgrade to latest version

2. Install new version of Artifactory on a new server and perform a [export/import](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/import-and-export) from old version.